# Foreign key constraint fails on drop table even if "ON DELETE SET NULL" is set

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
create table if not exists Emp(
  PId int not null primary key auto_increment,
  DId int,
  Name varchar(30) not null,
  LastName varchar(30) not null)
```

and

```
create table if not exists Wages(
  ZId int not null primary key auto_increment,
  PId int,
  amount int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (PId) REFERENCES Emp(PId) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL)
```

and when i try to drop table Emp i got: "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails".
What is wrong with this code? Why ON DELETE does not seem to work properly?

Comment: `ON DELETE` is about behaviour when you `DELETE` *within* the referenced table. `DROP` and `DELETE` are different things.

Comment: So the proper way to drop Emp is drop Wages first or just remove constraint ?